# Wrong output with Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jupyter

I try to learn a little bit about web scrapping with Python. Therefore, I bought a course from Udemy (Web Scraping and API Fundamentals in Python).

When the course introduced requests-html I get a different result in Jupyter Notebook than the lecturer has. After some trial and error and searching the internet I tried the same code in PyCharm. It turns out that the output in Jupyter and PyCharm are different, but PyCharm is correct.

The code is rather simple:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_football")
links = r.html.find("a")
print(links[5])
print(links[5].html)
```

The first print command results in the same correct output in Jupyter and PyCharm:

```
<Element 'a' class=('mw-jump-link',) href='#searchInput'>
```

However, the second print command produces two different results:

**PyCharm:**

```
<a class="mw-jump-link" href="#searchInput">Jump to search</a>
```

**Jupyter**

```
<a class="mw-jump-link" href="#searchInput">Jump to search</a>
<div id="mw-content-text" class="mw-body-content mw-content-ltr" lang="en" dir="ltr"><div class="mw-parser-output"><div class="shortdescription nomobile noexcerpt noprint searchaux" style="display:none">Team sport played with a spherical ball</div>
<style data-mw-deduplicate="TemplateStyles:r1033289096">.mw-parser-output .hatnote{font-style:italic}.mw-parser-output div.hatnote{padding-left:1.6em;margin-bottom:0.5em}.mw-parser-output .hatnote i{font-style:normal}.mw-parser-output .hatnote+link+.hatnote{margin-top:-0.5em}</style><div role="note" class="hatnote navigation-not-searchable">"Soccer team" and "Soccer" redirect here. For the band, see <a href="/wiki/Soccer_Team_(band)" title="Soccer Team (band)">Soccer Team (band)</a>. For other uses, see <a href="/wiki/Soccer_(disambiguation)" class="mw-disambig" title="Soccer (disambiguation)">Soccer (disambiguation)</a>.</div>
<link rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style" href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r1033289096"/><div role="note" class="hatnote navigation-not-searchable">This article is about the sport of association football. For other codes of football, see <a href="/wiki/Football" title="Football">Football</a>.</div>
<p class="mw-empty-elt">
</p>
...etc...
```

I only pasted a small snippet of the Jupyter output because the real output is much too long since  it is all html code until the very last closing tag:

It looks like the first line of the Jupyter output is correct, however, I don't know why Jupyter adds all the other stuff to its output.

The problem is not only ecstatic; I can't proceed with the course since the code will crash when I try to proceed with the next command `r.html.find("a", containing="wikipedia")` and I think it's due to the same reason.

I would be very grateful if someone can tell me how to fix the problem in Jupyter. I have already uninstalled and reinstalled the kernel and the requests-html package.

Comment: I tried this out and got the shorter output for both Python and Jupyter.

Comment: I can't reproduce your behaviour. Both give the same correct output. Perhaps you assigned to *links* in a different cell?